# Strange route behaviour angularJS with /?#/

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m actually facing a problem with routes in AngularJS.
In fact, when I launch one of my page for the first time, the current url is "http://www.test.com/#/roadmaps/edit".

When I click on any button of the page, my page refreshes and gives me a new URL like : "http://www.test.com/?#/roadmaps/edit" with the "?" before the "#".

So everytime I fill the different input in my page and click a button, the first time it refreshes (problematic...) and make the "?" symbol appears in the URL.

Do you have an idea ?

This is my actual routing function:

```
function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/roadmaps/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/roadmap_edit.html',
            controller: 'RoadMapEditCtrl'
        }).
        when('/roadmaps/edit/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/roadmap_edit.html',
            controller: 'RoadMapEditCtrl'
        })
}
```

The first line is for adding a roadmap and the second one to modify.

Can you help me ?

Thanks for advance

EDIT :

This is one of the buttons that causes this problem :

```
<li>
 <button style="margin-top:10px;" ng-click="selectAll()">Tout {{selectionner}}
</button>
</li>
```

And the selectAll() function :

```
var isSelectedJour = false;
    $scope.selectAll = function () {
        if (isSelectedJour) {
            $scope.selectionner = "cocher";
        } else {
            $scope.selectionner = "décocher";
        }

        isSelectedJour = !isSelectedJour;

        $scope.mo = isSelectedJour;
        $scope.tu = isSelectedJour;
        $scope.we = isSelectedJour;
        $scope.th = isSelectedJour;
        $scope.fr = isSelectedJour;
        $scope.sa = isSelectedJour;
        $scope.su = isSelectedJour;
    };
```

Comment: The routing code you provided looks fine, the problem is elsewhere. Please provide the page itself where you state the links and stuff.

Comment: Post the full `.config` method definition block

Comment: This is my config method

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can contour it using

```
function config($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/roadmaps/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/roadmap_edit.html',
            controller: 'RoadMapEditCtrl'
        }).
        when('/roadmaps/edit/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/roadmap_edit.html',
            controller: 'RoadMapEditCtrl'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

Comment: The # isnt a problem :/ it's the "?" symbol that is problematic

Comment: Think it happens because you are sending some parameter in your URL. If I found the answer I will post here for you again. Hugs!

Comment: Tested without the route parametered and there is the same problem

Comment: mmm, I tested in my project here and the url didnt show any "?". How about your code html, are you using href, ng-href or ui-sref ? Or are you just calling the url in your browser ?

Comment: I dont use anyone of these, it appears on button elements that has only ng-click functions associated, without any redirection inside the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party here, but here is the cause and two solutions: [ReactJS with React Router - strange routing behaviour on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305744/reactjs-with-react-router-strange-routing-behaviour-on-chrome). The cause is ANY button click getting treated as a submit and the form not having a submit action target. One solution is to add a preventDefault event handler. As I noted in a comment, all I needed to do to fix it was change `<button>` to `<span>`.