# Using react-router history to change path adds ? before #

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js

I'm using react router in my redux web app when i try to update the route using

```
this.props.history.push('/route')
```

It adds a ? to the address like so

```
https://website.com/?#/route
```

When it should look like this

```
https://website.com/#/route
```

This causes my single page application to reload.

Things i tried:

- upgrading react router to latest (2.0.1, currently using 1.0.3) didn't help
- we're using hash history, switching to browser history didn't help

Comment: Switching to browser history should work. You might be missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because you're using `<form>` with React, and it's submitting a form.

See this answer for a better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32570827/5498949

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
import { Router, Route, BrowserHistory } from 'react-router';

let bHistory = BrowserHistory({
  queryKey: false
});
```

It will diable the random string appearing in the route path.